# NodeJS, Passport: how to change user's password by admin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I start to make admin panel for modify users. I want to have ability to change users passwords by admin. For authentication I use passport. The I change user's password - the data is saving to mongo, but after that, user can't logIn to site.
Please, help.

My Passport configuration:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id)
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password_first',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },

        function(req, email, password, done) {

            User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, function(req, res){
                        res.send({error: true})
                    });

                if (!user.isAuthenticated )

                    return done(null, false, function(req, res){
                        res.send({error: true})
                    });

                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, function(req, res){
                        res.send({error: true})
                    });

                if(user){
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            });

        }));
```

User model:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    date                : Date,
    role                : String,
    newRole             : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'newRole'},
    authToken           : { type: String, required : true, unique:true },
    isAuthenticated     : { type: Boolean, required : true },
    username            : String,
    email               : String,
    password_first      : String,
    firstName           : String,
    lastName            : String,
    address             : String,
    phone               : String,
    resetPasswordToken  : String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date });

Methods:

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password_first);
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And finally:

```
exports.changeByAdmin = function (req, res, next) {

   User.findById({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, updateUser) {

        if(err) return next(err);
        if (!updateUser) return next();

        updateUser.email = req.body.email;

        updateUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;

        updateUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;

        updateUser.address = req.body.address;

        updateUser.phone = req.body.phone;

        updateUser.password_first = updateUser.generateHash(req.body.password_first);

        updateUser.save(function(err, updateUser) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            if(!updateUser) return next();
                res.send({ success: true });
        });
    });
};
```

If I change only email of user, the user can login with new email and old password, but if I change password - user can't login. Please, advise the solution of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Is that your complete user model? Is there a pre-save hook somewhere that's hashing the password a second time?

Comment: @Kryten that's being done (manually) in `changeByAdmin`.

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? Does `validPassword` fail when the user tries to log in? Is the user document in the database properly updated? Does `updateUser.password_first` make sense right before saving it? Etc...

Comment: @robertklep  After `updateUser.save()`,  the user document in the database is updated, password_first in the database is changing, but then I try to login, `validPassword()` fail. I think the problem is in the passport, may be I can change the password only for user in session?

Comment: Try and see if you can validate the generated hash against the new password from a standalone piece of code.